# How to fix AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy1'?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a python beginner I'm facing issue on **numpy**

This is my code:

```
import numpy1 as np

a = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])

print(a)
```

Error:

*AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy1' has no attribute 'array' (most likely due to a circular import)*

how to fix this?

Comment: is it numpy or numpy1?

Comment: Please post some code for `numpy1` if it is code you've written

Comment: Its fixed for me after changing the name of Python file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its fixed for me after changing the name of Python file, because 'numpy' is a build in file name.